# Sweet and sticky potato

Tags: potatoes, food-identification, sweet-potatoes

I have just made very simple french fries (cutting and frying in oil) with some potatoes bought today  that turned out to be very different to my usual potatoes. They taste quite sweet, almost in the middle between a normal potato and a sweet potato. They also stuck together a bit while I was frying them, which has never happened before. The potatoes are unlabelled, but they’re fairly small (but not baby potatoes) and look like completely normal potatoes. What type of potato could they be and what is the best way to cook it? They made terrible french fries.

Comment: A photo may be useful....

Comment: Is it possible the potatoes have been stored too cold (4°C or so)?